# FlinkKinesisProducer unable to publish events to kinesis stream in AWS me-central-1(UAE) region

Tags: java, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, aws-sts, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am having a Flink KDA (now Managed Apache Flink) application in one of the AWS account.
Here we are publishing some events from **KDA (us-west-2 region)** to kinesis stream in other account on **me-central-1 region**, but this fails with an **UnrecognizedClientException**
After some investigation we found that STS token generated from global endpoints are valid only in the regions which are by default enabled by AWS and STS tokens generated by regional endpoints are valid in all regions [Ref Documentation].
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/accounts/latest/reference/manage-acct-regions.html).
Is there any way in **FlinkKinesisProducer.java** where we can override this behavior of using regional endpoints instead of global endpoints.